# Can anyone explain the below code?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
class Program
{
    class Person {
        protected int Age {get; set;}
        protected string Name {get; set;}
    }
    class Student : Person {
        public Student(string nm) {
            Name = nm;
        }
        public void Speak() {
            Console.Write("Name: "+Name);
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student s = new Student("David");
        s.Speak();
    }
}
```

--->Output: Name:David

In the above code we have 'get' and 'set' methods used..

Now...

using System;
 class Program
    {
        class Person {

```
        protected string Name;
    }
    class Student : Person {
        public Student(string nm) {
            Name = nm;
        }
        public void Speak() {
            Console.Write("Name: "+Name);
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student s = new Student("David");
        s.Speak();
    }
}
```

--->Output: Name:David

Here i have removed the 'get' and 'set' methods but the output was same. Then what is the use of those methods?

Comment: Your question is unclear. There are no methods named `get` or `set` in the code you posted.

Comment: an item declared on a class without `get` and `set` is considered a field, not a propery;  fields are handled differently.  the `{get;set;}` without actual functions is called "auto property accessors", making the item a property with an automatic backing field.

Comment: as an example, `Student.Name` would work in the first example, but would not work in the second example.

Answer (score 2):

You can make sure that no wrong inputs are made, or basically execute additional code whenever the property is changed...